# pop up a window in xcode

Tags: iphone

i have a search bar in navigation bar now whenever user press on that i want to drop down a view having 
2 text field and a cancel button , but i dont know how to do that

kindly suggest me

Thanks

Comment: This question isn't about Xcode. It's about an iPhone project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your view controller implement the [`UISearchBarDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and then implementing the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` method (by having it show your text fields + button, and returning `NO`).

The whole idea feels like a possible HIG violation, so proceed at your own risk if you're submitting to the App Store, as Apple could reject your app for behaving in a particularly non-standard way.